# Which material for a sink bucket?

Tags: sink, materials, plastic

I'm thinking about making a small sink for my DIY lab. Since there is no running water or drain, I was thinking about something similar to a camping sink like [this one](https://www.instructables.com/Field-Sink/).

I'd make some modifications (e.g. using a ceramic basin rather than a plastic one, since it will be fixed).

Now, for the water reservoir any container is fine, but I have doubts about the material of the drain plumbing and container. I'd usually use it to wash the hands (so only water + soap), but I'd also occasionally use it to wash tools and items, which can include also chemicals (e.g. ferric chloride to etch PCBs).

What material is usually used in these cases, and what are its limitations? (e.g. this plastic is ok for acids but when used with gasoline breaks).

For instance I found containers and pipes in PE or PVC or PP; is any of these materials suitable?

Comment: Gasoline? In a sink? Inside your house? Darwin award coming up.

Comment: *DIY lab. Since there is no running water or drain* - I'm guessing this is in a shed or detached garage.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, this really isn't about home improvement. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about home improvement.

Comment: @Ecnerwal the "gasoline" part was because I know that some plastic containers are not suitable for gasoline storage (because gasoline can "melt" them). That was just an example to show the kind of reply I'd like to receive: suggested material and associated limitations. I want to assure you, though, that no gasoline will be put in that storage container; I used that as an example because it is the first example of "not suitable plastic" that came to my mind

Comment: @DanielGriscom can you further explain why you think this is not suitable? Is it because it is not for a house but rather for a (DIYer's) lab? I think a garage lab is part of the house, this is definitely an improvement and the question is about the materials to use to get this done. TBH, though, I came to this website because of the "diy" name in it, and I did not consider the "Home Improvement", but after reading the page you linked I'm more confident that this is the right place to ask. If not, can you please point me to the more appropriate stackexchange site to ask?

Comment: You're asking about appropriate materials for a lab sink, which is either choosing materials, or non-home-related, neither of which is on-topic.

Comment: poly pro would likely be the most durable option, but if solvents are watered down it shouldn't make a lot of diff.

Comment: @DanielGriscom Believe me when I'm saying I'm not trying to be a troll, but I'm genuinely asking to understand how to best use this website. This said, in the page you linked there is a box saying "Ask about ..." "Which tools, materials, and best practices for home improvement task". So asking for materials is definitely on topic here. As for the usage, this is not for a professional lab, but for a DIYer's lab. Would it change if I say it will be my garage's sink?

Comment: @dandavis I suppose you mean Polypropylene. Do you think it is better than Polyethylene for this purpose?

Comment: And, it's about shopping, which is also off-topic. Also note that I was only one of five that thought this was off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

#1- Plastic Buckets are **cheap**. Use one 'til it is no longer usable, buy three.  (*My favorite are the Lowe's buckets. I have put all kind of nasty stuff in them.*)

I lived for many years with a water jug on a shelf above a double sink with  plastic buckets under each bowl (*and a camp toilet in the bathroom*).  The key  to remember is **LOOK UNDER THE SINK** to see how full the buckets are.

A small [galvanized trash can](https://www.belson.com/Galvanized-Trash-Cans-Lids-Pails) would hold more liquid. I am not sure how water tight they are. I have had ones that held water. Maybe a stainless steel one from a restaurant supply house would be a good investment.

A galvanized bucket would be a good choice.

[image]
Photo courtesy of [It's still life](http://%20A%20small%20%5Bgalvanized%20trash%20can%5D%5B1%5D%20would%20hold%20more%20liquid.) No affiliation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd avoid metal because of rust and corrosion, so I'd go with plastic.
Since not all plastics are made equal, do you think some material has advantages over the others (usually I find around PP, PE or HDPE containers)